# How to create a link to google live traffic maps from my Application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing Live traffic data in my application. I tried many ways to add google traffic data into my application. I didn't succeed. Decided to integrate google maps live traffic link  into my Application. How to do that? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Maps API for Android v2 SDK, you can use :

`googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);`

to display traffics layer on Google Maps.

more : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setTrafficEnabled(boolean)